# Change of variable of a numerically solved integral

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, physics

I have the following function that numerically integrates a function on the interval $\left[ 2, 100 \right]$

```
Int[b_] := 
  NIntegrate[((1 - 2/Sqrt[r^2])^(3/2) Sqrt[r^4/(
    r^4 - 2 (r^2)^(3/2) + b^2 (-4 - r^2 + 4 Sqrt[r^2]))])/
   r^2, {r, 2, 100}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
```

The result only depends on $b$, so I intend to make the change $b = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. I thought of something like

```
Int[b_] := f[b] /. b -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
```

But it's not working. My goal is to make the variable change to plot the intensity profile with DensityPlot and get something like this (Figure 4 in [this article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1674-1137/ac67fe/pdf))

[image]

Comment: You could try `ListDensityPlot` ! But have a look at your integrand, `FunctionDomain[...]` gives the restriction `r > 2 && b^2 (-2 + r) < r^3`

Comment: Int[x] for x>=6 becomes complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps onedimensional plot is sufficient?

```
Plot[Int[b], {b, 0, 5}, ColorFunction -> Hue,PlotStyle -> Thickness[Large]]
```

[image]

or using `ListDensityPlot`

```
zw = Table[{b Cos[phi], b Sin[phi], Int[b]}, {b, Subdivide[0, 5, 25]}, {phi, Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50]}];
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[zw, 1] , ColorFunctionScaling -> True,ColorFunction -> Hue ]
```

[image]

or using `DensityPlot`

```
DensityPlot[int[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], Element[{x, y}, Disk[{0, 0}, 5]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!